# Replace ObjectId('11111111') with ObjectId('2222222') at any occurence

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo collection in which at any depth or within array elements there may occur ObjectId('11111111') as a value.
I need to replace it everywhere with ObjectId('2222222').
Is there an easy way of doing this in mongo?

Comment: You can use aggregate if you have array to be changed you can use $match then $in checks mongo aggreate once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dump the collection to extended json, open the dump in a text editor, replace the values, then load the dump back into the database.

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved a lot of time for me. I was struggling with those endless nested array elements trying not to place $ sign into wrong place of the $set, but your solution saved me from any mistakes. Really appreciate!